# What does "a golden fruit" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Patience bears a golden fruit!

In the above sentence, what does "a golden fruit" mean?

Comment: Source? I would guess "golden" refers to "valuable", though (like something made of gold).

Comment: What @user3169 said. Same figurative usage as *a golden opportunity, the golden rule,* etc. Nothing to do with physical appearance or composition. [Definition 3:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/golden) *special; wonderful.*

Comment: Either it's a metaphor for a valuable reward or very desirable outcome, or the speaker just really likes [golden delicious apples](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Delicious). A common saying with a similar meaning is *Good things come to those who wait.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "to bear fruit" means to create something of value, or have a positive result.  For instance, someone might ask if an investigation has born fruit as a poetic way to ask if new information has been found.  It is used fairly often in religious texts, but is otherwise rare in common use.  Anyone who uses that phrase is either trying to sound like religious scripture or being overly colorful.

In this phrase, "Patience bears a golden fruit!", the source sounds like religious scripture.  The phrase has nearly the same meaning without "golden" - "Patience bears fruit!" would also mean you can expect a positive result from patience.  However, by specifying a *golden* fruit, the source is trying to reinforce that this is an exceptionally valuable and desirable result.

Comment: *"It is used fairly often in religious texts, but is otherwise rare in common use."* - I've heard "bears fruit" a number of times in a business context.

Answer (score 2):

Golden fruit may be an allusion to the Golden Apples that Hercules stole. One of the major goals of alchemy was to turn base metals into gold (because gold was so desirable). There is also the fable of Midas who was cursed with turning anything he touched into gold. This last is noteworthy because having the "golden touch" and being able to create any number of golden objects would be believed to be very desirable. You should familiarize yourself with those stories. In this case, "fruit" is being used to mean "product" or "result" (metaphorically) and "golden" means "very valuable" or " very desirable". Hence 'golden fruit' means "very desirable reward".

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard this saying before. However, from context, I would assume that it means "a great reward."

The overall sentence is just saying that if you exercise patience, you will be rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "golden fruit" but golden apples come up in mythology as, for example, "food of the gods". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_apple). There are also stories of golden eggs - e.g. the expression

> the goose that lays the golden egg.

I wonder if partly the idea is that if you had a tree that produced golden apples (or golden fruit of any kind) then you would become immensely wealthy.

So in context here the expression implies that patience brings a very valuable reward.